# Not able to print address from Reverse Geocoding in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, reverse-geocoding

I reffred many questions from Stack overflow and implemented the above procedure. But I am unable to get the adress. Please let me know If i missed something.. ?
myLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id1);

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),Locale.getDefault());
try {
    address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (address.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < address.get(0)
                .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            display = "";
            display += address.get(0).getAddressLine(i)
                    + "\n";
        }
        }

} catch (Exception e2) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
myLoc.setText("Current Location:"+display);
System.out.println(display);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reverse geo coding to and Google apis to get address from latitude and longitude.

**Reverse Geo Coding**:

```
 double currentLatitude;
    double currentLongitude;

void getAddress(){
        try{
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = 
                gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++){
                    Address address =  addresses.get(i);
                    int maxIndex = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                    for (int x = 0; x <= maxIndex; x++ ){
                        result.append(address.getAddressLine(x));
                        result.append(",");
                    }               
                    result.append(address.getLocality());
                    result.append(",");
                    result.append(address.getPostalCode());
                    result.append("\n\n");
                }
                addressText.setText(result.toString());
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            addressText.setText(ex.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
```

**Google API:** See this api which retrun address from latitude and longitude

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=17.734884,83.299507&sensor=true

[To know more read this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude values. But after adding your code, I am still not getting reverse geocoding :(

Answer (score 1):

1. [getMaxAddressLineIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getMaxAddressLineIndex%28%29) returns an **index** which start from zero and thus your for-loop condition should be *0 <= maxIndex* instead of *0 < maxIndex*
2. You overwrite previous address lines on every iteration by assigning **display = "";** and thus will end up with the last address line only. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Can't believe no one upvote this for the answer 1. yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another good idea is to implement the LocationListener interface and register your Activity as a listener using LocationManager `requestLocationUpdates()` method. You can then override `onLocationUpdate()` to be informed whenever the location of the device changes. You provide the `requestLocationUpdates()` method the minimum amount of time that must pass before you will accept another update and how far the device must move before you get an update.

Comment: That will get him the location coordinates (which he already seems to have) not the address.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to get complete address. In case you want **country name** 
 ,  **state** etc seperately .Then, I will not prefer you this method .

```
public class ParentHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ...

private Geocoder geocoder;
private TextView mAddressTxtVu;

     ...


// I assume that you got latitude and longitude correctly 

mLatitude  =  20.23232
mLongitude =  32.999

String errorMessage = "";

geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses = null;

try {
          addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                   mlattitude,
                   mlongitude,
                   1);
  } catch (IOException e) {
          errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
          Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, e);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                    // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
          errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
          Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " + "Latitude = " + mlattitude +", 
         Longitude = " + mlongitude, illegalArgumentException);
  }

  // Handle case where no address was found.
  if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
         if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                  errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                  Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
         }

  } else {
         Address address = addresses.get(0);
         ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

         // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
         // join them, and send them to the thread.
         for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                  addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
         }
         // Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));


   mAddressTxtVu.setText(TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                            addressFragments));
                }
```